# Spark : Explode a pair of nested columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark Version 2.1

I am reading a file into Spark `dataframe` with following format:

```
{
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "elements": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "a"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "b"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "c"
    }]
}
```

It contains an `array` of nested elements, now I want to `explode` the `elements` array to get the flat json structure. I am using the below code:

```
var dfExploded = df
    .withColumn("id", 
      explode(df.col("elements.id")))
    .withColumn("name",
      explode(df.col("elements.name")));
```

It seems to be returning cartesian product (e.g. I am getting 9 elements in the result whereas I only want 3). Is there any way I can specify a pair of nested columns to `explode` function?

Comment: maybe turn Id + name into tuple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly you would want you can try this:

```
 val exploded = df.withColumn("elements", explode($"elements"))
 exploded.show()
 >> +--------+------+------+
 >> |elements|field1|field2|
 >> +--------+------+------+
 >> |   [1,a]|value1|value2|
 >> |   [2,b]|value1|value2|
 >> |   [3,c]|value1|value2|
 >> +--------+------+------+
```

This first step basically turns the array into separate records. You need to do it on the array itself (elements) rather than elements inside

Next you can do

```
 val flattened = exploded.select("elements.*", "field1", "field2")
 flattened.show()
 >> +---+----+------+------+
 >> | id|name|field1|field2|
 >> +---+----+------+------+
 >> |  1|   a|value1|value2|
 >> |  2|   b|value1|value2|
 >> |  3|   c|value1|value2|
 >> +---+----+------+------+
```

To flatten the elements

Comment: Thanks for your input. Now I understand the difference between single `explode` with `select` and multiple `explode` calls. Works like a charm :)

Comment: Nice answer, can I further ask, how to manage this if there is no "id" element and it must be extracted (e.g. using `posexplode`) as the order in the array `elements`?

Comment: @PavelProchazka Can you give an example?

Comment: just as the aforementioned example with dataframe given by
`{"field1": "value1",    "field2": "value2", "elements": [{"name": "a" },   {"name": "b"}, { "name": "c" }]}`, that is without `id`. Desired result is exactly the same as `flattened` in your  answer, where id is given by order in the array.

Comment: @PavelProchazka You can try something like this: df.select($"field1", $"field2", posexplode($"elements").as(Seq("id", "extracted"))).select($"field1", $"field2", $"id", $"extracted.*").show()